# Write out conditional sum $(4l-1)\Sigma_{p=0}1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I currently trying to understand the following paper https://www.mathnet.ru/links/d3f454cf37f4a76bfbff3dca0294b846/ivm8674.pdf
On page 131 for $\sigma_1$ a conditional sum is described as

$\sigma_1=(4l-1)\Sigma_{p=0}\frac{a_{2i-2n+p-1}a_{2n-p-1}a_{p}}{(4i+2p-3)a_{2i+p-2}}\dots$ with the condition $(l=i-n+p,1\le l \le \gamma)$

I have difficulties to write out the series. For simplicity we assume that
$\sigma_1=(4l-1)\Sigma_{p=0}1$ with the same condition $(l=i-n+p,1\le l \le \gamma)$ when $n=1,i=1,\gamma=3$. This would mean that $p$ can only take the value $1,2,3$. This mean that $\Sigma_{p=0}1=1+1+1$. What I don't understand, what happens with $(4l-1)$.

As $p$ can take 3 different values, I do not know how to write out the whole series $(4l-1)\Sigma_{p=0}1$

Comment: End of p130 says: *Substitute (1.6), (1.7) into (1.2), (1.4); using the formulae [...], rewrite the products $P_m(\tau)P_n^1(\tau)$ and $P_m^1(\tau) \frac{dP_n(\tau)}{d\tau}$, which are introduced by simplifications into the nonlinear parts of the equations, in terms of the "adjoint" (=associated?) Legendre functions $P_i^1(\tau)$. The summation ends with the first-occurring term with zero index. Then equate the coefficients: at first, of the Reynolds number powers; secondly, of the $P_i^1(\tau)$*. Can there be a summation over $l$? Note there are **two** conditions $(l=...)$ on the same line.

Comment: I think the second condition applies to the second series in the line. I do not find a hint for a summation over $l$. It first appears in the definition of $\sigma_1$

Comment: $l$ appears as an index in $\frac{dP_{2j}}{d\tau}$ with seemingly the same role. Interestingly the same unclear notation appears in a subsequent [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01016244) that was translated. I fear the easiest you can do is to use a CAS...

Comment: Yes I found this one also. A colleague suggests that $(4l-l1)$ should be inside the sum series. I will calculate some case and compare to numerical result. I think there is no way around. Maybe this is soviet typical notation for readability.